# Confused on getting DataTables Render Text Helper?

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I am trying to render my DataTables table so that it allows HTML characters to be shown.

From my reading it seems that this can be done using the DataTables Text Helper (as seen here https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers)

In the example they give they simply put:

```
    data: 'product',
    render: $.fn.dataTable.render.text()
```

However when I have tried this it appears to do nothing at all as all the columns in my DataTable still don't show any HTML special characters (and no errors). I understand that my code is more complex than this example, but is there something simple I am missing?

```
var dataTableZ = $('#results_table').DataTable({
          data: data.value,
          render: $.fn.dataTable.render.text(),
          /*
           Unrelated Code surrounding buttons and column ordering
          */
          columns: searchColumnDetails
        });
```

(Where data.value is some data coming back from an Ajax call)

I have tried looking for answers to my question and it seems I am running a version of DataTables that includes this function (1.10.20), but none of the examples I could find online shed any light into my confusion.

Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Managed to find an answer to my question on the DataTables Forums!

Datatables doesn't have an option called render. There is a columns.render. You need to use either columns or columnDefs to to apply the render. Something like this:

> columnDefs: [   {
>       targets: 0,
>       render: $.fn.dataTable.render.text()   } ]

By putting this code into my code, it worked as intended.
Forum Post: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/59325/render-text-helper-not-showing-html/p1?new=1